# resx static reference programmatically

Tags: c#

I use the resx file for the language localization,
how is possible update it and create also, the static reference
as you obtain opening and saving the file using visual studio.

When I add a new entry in the resx file I can retrieve it through the name but not through the static field.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The static field is created during compile time, the compiler reads the .Resx file and creates named fields. When you update your file AFTER compilation, you can't get static field names.

Comment: It seems that static fields are created opening and save the resx file with visual studio also without compile. It could be very useful create them programmatically but also compiling the project avoid to open and save the resx file.